# Repl ram is glitched and seems to be full without reason

Tags: node.js

Something is highly wrong with repl.
I tried to find solutions on the internet but couldn't find anything.
[image: picture]

I have no code but my ram is still so high...
This is a node.js project.

Comment: What program is the screenshot from? I think this is the ram usage from the program.

Comment: I can see that you added "Node.js" (no need, by the way, since it was already tagged `node.js`) but there is no Node.js official editor, so what is the screenshot taken from? Node.js runs on a console and this is not a console.

Comment: Regardless, the answer is that this is not the RAM usage from Node.js but of the program that you are running.

Comment: I'm using repl (https://repl.it).

Comment: Ok. Node.js REPL (the command line, not the web site you are loading) takes about 33 megabytes of RAM on my computer. I'm not sure what the RAM usage listed there refers to - possibly the memory usage of a container running the editor. You should ask this question on the repl.it forums.

Comment: fyi the container you enter into is running more then just node, go into shell run `htop` install it then your see what processes your runner is running, the value of ram usage, CPU usage is all that is running, not just node

Comment: ohhhh alright thanks a lot for the info :)